# Are there any packages in Ubuntu that allow routing on application layer level?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, routing

I would like to route packages received by a VM host to different VM guest, on basis of application layer, in particular domains given in urls. It is impossible to route on network layer level, since IP address limitations (to the outside) do not allow this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nginx is a light-weight proxy that can do this with web and e-mail traffic.

Answer (score 2):

You mention URLs so forgive me if I make an assumption that this is web traffic. Could you put an apache + mod_proxy on the domU / VM host and direct the traffic based on URL that way?